# Calculate $2^{48} \equiv x \mod 140$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, totient-function

I've calculated the following equation and I've got this:
[image: My Solution]

Does there exist an easier solution?

Comment: You might have a look at [How do I compute $a^b\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand).

Comment: $2^{48} \equiv x mod 20 \implies 4|x$.  Let $y = x/4$.  $2^{46} \equiv y \mod 5$.  $2^2 \equiv -1 \mod 5$ so $2^4 \equiv -1 \mod 5$ so $2^2 = 4 \equiv y \mod 5$ so $2^48 \equiv 16 \mod 20$....

Comment: Actually, I'm kind of perplexed by why you were given this problem.  Have you learned that if $\gcd(m,a) = 1$ that $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$ yet?  I'm assuming not as this seems to be in introduction to the idea but...

Comment: $2^{\phi(140)} = (2^{\phi(35)})^{\phi(4)} \equiv 1 \mod 35$  So $2^{\phi(140)} \equiv 1 + 35k \mod 140$. As $4|2^{\phi(140)}$ and $4|140$ then $4|1 + 35k$.  So $1 + 35k = 36$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have obtained the exponent as $48=\varphi(140)$.

We could use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) in combination with [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Namely we have 
$$2^{\varphi(35)}\equiv 1 \pmod{35}$$
by Fermat's theorem. Consequently, we also have $2^{\varphi(140)}\equiv 1 \pmod{35}$.
It is clear that $4\mid 2^{48}$, hence $2^{\varphi{140}}\equiv 0 \pmod4$.

The system of congruences
\begin{align*}
2^{\varphi(140)}&\equiv 1 \pmod{35}\\
2^{\varphi(140)}&\equiv 0 \pmod{4}
\end{align*}
has a unique solution modulo $4\cdot 35=140$. It is not difficult to find that it is 
$$2^{\varphi(140)}\equiv 36 \pmod{140},$$
since we only have four possibilities $1$, $36$, $71$ and $106$ fulfilling the first congruence.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{48} = (2^8)^6 = 256^6 \equiv(-24)^6 = 576^3 \equiv 16^3 = 4096 \equiv 36 \pmod {140}$

Answer (score 1):

$2^{48} \equiv 0 \bmod 4$

$2^{48} = (2^2)^{24} \equiv (-1)^{24} \equiv  1 \bmod 5$

$2^{48} = (2^3)^{16} \equiv (1)^{24} \equiv  1 \bmod 7$

So $2^{48} \bmod 140$ must be a multiple of $4$ of the form $1+35k$. We get $36$ for $k=1$.